Android + Kotlin. How to fix strange GalleryView layout behaviour?
I'm developing a mobile app for a company, and for a week now I've been struggling with one layout problem that I can't figure out.
I have a sheet of GalleryViews arranged as a ribbon in a fragment, and separated by date. These Header+GalleryView elements are added via code depending on the situation.
Gallery layout example

And this approach has 2 problems. One is rather obvious, the other is not at all.

Galleries hijack the functionality of the slide gesture for scrolling, making the UX jagged and unpleasant. This is a consequence of a mis-implementation through a bunch of galleries from a past employee. Ideally this would all be replaced by a single gallery, but I don't understand how to group them by feature then.

The height of gallery elements behaves erratically, and is extremely annoying in some situations. It seems to be related to the position on the screen at the moment of generation. In some cases, the gallery height becomes extremely low, and instead of fully displaying all the elements within itself, it starts offering to scroll through them within a single gallery.


I'll attach a video for a more visual demonstration:
Here you can see the normal gallery layout, and the jerkiness when trying to scroll:
https://youtube.com/shorts/gphWU1UjQUI
and then suddenly, in the next tab, it behaves completely differently.
https://youtu.be/k08G7XPNoeA
Here is the XML layout that is used to render this page:
Fragment layout:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/inner_content_view"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <!-- Grouped gallery elements will be inserted here  -->
            </LinearLayout>
        </ScrollView>
    </androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

    <include
        android:id="@+id/include"
        layout="@layout/include_loading_view"
        tools:visibility="gone" />

    <include
        layout="@layout/include_error_view"
        app:layout_anchor="@+id/include"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="center"
        tools:visibility="gone" />
</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

Procedurally added gallery element:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/comment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingVertical="10dp"
            android:paddingLeft="13dp"
            android:paddingRight="13dp"
            android:textSize="13sp"
            tools:text="Комментарий"
            android:textAlignment="gravity"
            android:background="@color/photoreport_comment_background"/>

        <ru.projectA.android.components.mediagallery.GalleryView
            android:id="@+id/gallery_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    </LinearLayout>



</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

I have tried all variations of wrap_content and match_size in the sweep at every possible level, it doesn't affect the final result at all.
setting min_height affects the minimum size of the gallery, but does not solve the problem that the maximum size occasionally does not match the content of the gallery.
I suspect the problem lies in the standard GalleryView, which is not adapted to work when there are a lot of them on the screen.
I'd like to find either a way to turn it all into 1 gallery capable of separating items by category (or by date), or a fix for the height bug in the galleries.

The problem with GalleryView only its seems its addeding scrollable on rendered photos which makes the parent scroll view + each gallery section scroll separately.
